# Touch doesn't work Xcode 7 iOS simulator 9

Tags: xcode, touch, ios-simulator, ios9, xcode7

Since I updated Xcode to 7 and to El capitan, touch doesn't work anymore on the Simulator (iOS 9).

I have checked all the userInteractionEnabled cases and the problem seems to come from somewhere else.

Comment: Where you want the touch event?

Comment: Please be more specific.  It's working for everyone else.  Can you provide sample code?

Comment: True, it was a problem with UITextView that now needs at least 10 characters, do you have anything to not have to changed all these manually ?